# How to validate a form with radio group in CodeIgniter

Tags: arrays, forms, codeigniter, validation

I have a form that presents questions and answers from a survey. User can select between 5 radio buttons - to choose answer of questions. They are array and the key is `question_id` - each question has these 5 radio buttons and they differ on this key.Could you help me with form validation?
Now if you choose answer for one of the questions, form submits. It has to submit only if all questions have answers. That's my view:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <?php
$survey_id = $this->uri->segment(3);
$question_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
$att=array('id'=>'form');
echo form_open('index/survey_fill/' .$survey_id .'/'. $question_id , $att); 
    echo "<table border="0" id='questionsTable' >";
echo "<tr><th>Въпрос</th></tr>";
 echo validation_errors();
 $index = 0;
 foreach ($question as $row)
 {
  echo "<tr id='$index'>";
  $index++;
 ?>
  
     <td> 
  <?php echo "$row->question"; ?><br/>
  <?php echo "<input type='hidden' name='question_id' value='$row->question_id' />"; ?>
  <?php 
   
  $data=array(
   'name' =>  'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
   'value' => '5',
   'class' => 'answer'

  );

  echo "<input type='hidden' name='survey_id' value='$row->survey_id'>"; 
  
  echo form_radio($data); 
  echo " 5 ";
  $data=array(
   'name' =>  'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
   'value' => '4',
   'class' => 'answer'
  );
  echo form_radio($data);
  echo " 4 ";
  $data=array(
   'name' => 'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
   'value' => '3',
   'class' => 'answer'
   
  );
  echo form_radio($data);
  echo " 3 ";
  $data=array(
   'name' => 'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
   'value' => '2',
   'class' => 'answer'
  );
  echo form_radio($data);
  echo " 2 ";
  $data=array(
   'name' => 'answer['.$row->question_id.']',
   'value' => '1',
   'class' => 'answer'
  );
  echo form_radio($data);
  echo " 1 ";
  ?>
  </td></tr>
   
 <?php 
 }

?>  

 
</table>

<?php echo "<input type='hidden' name='question_id' value='$row->question_id' />"; ?>
  <?php  echo '<input type="submit" id="button" name = "submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success">';
  ?>

</form>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

My controller is:

```html
public function survey_fill()
    { 
    
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('answer[]', 'Answer', 'required');      
    
        if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
        {

            $this->survey_show();
        }
        else 
        {

      if ($this->user_model->survey_fill()) 
         {
                
                header('Refresh: 2; url=/survey/index.php/index/surveys_show');          
         }

            else 
            {
                $this->load->model('user_model'); 
                $data['survey'] =$this->user_model->survey_show();
                $data['dynamic_view'] = 'survey_show';
                $data['menu']=$this->menu_model->get_menu();
                $this->load->view('templates/main',$data); 

      }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1) Set the required attribute in your data array like

```
$data = array('name' => 'answer['.$row->question_id.']', 'required' => 'required');
```

2) Set the form validation for each of your answer[$question_id] variables.

```
foreach($questions as $question){
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('answer['.$question->id.']', 'Question '.$question->id, 'required');
}
```

I'd stick with 1.

Comment: Thank you! It works, I used the second, because it gave me undefined for question_id for the first example. I write form validation in controller and used example 2 and wrote query $questions there. :)

Comment: Glad I could help! And undefined? Were you still passing in your other values? I'd be interested in knowing what exactly didn't work for the first one for you.

Comment: Becaurse in that function that I write form validation, I don't have this query, that's why 'question_id' is undefined. I added: $query = $this->user_model->getSurvey($this->uri->segment(3), $this->uri->segment(4));
    $questions = $query->result();

    foreach($questions as $question){
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('answer['.$question->question_id.']', 'Question '.$question->question_id, 'required');
    }  and now It's ok. :)

Comment: Oh, no no no. I meant that $data array that you're passing into form_radio in your view as `<?php echo form_radio($data); ?>` I'm so sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Great! That'd be the best way to handle it. :)